# I visited shanghai a few years ago and bought a necklace. Unfortunately, I don't remember what the necklace says. Can someone help me translate?

Tags: simplified-characters

Please help me translate this! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ok5z.jpg)

Comment: it's a backwards 想得美 - which means "you wish!"

Answer (score 4):

It is“想得美”,means "like your wish"or "don't be naive";)